# How to implement a generic recursive interface?

Tags: java, generics

Another case of java generics confusion...

I am defining a hierarchy of interfaces which must include a method to return a list of that interface type. This is a standard use case for the recursive generic pattern (or whatever the name for this is):

```
interface SuperInter<T extends SuperInter<T>> {
    List<T> getEffects();
}
```

Now when I extends this interface:

```
interface SubInter extends SuperInter<SubInter> {}
```

I can implement the sub-interface and have the correct method to implement:

```
class SubImpl implements SubInter {

    @Override
    public List<SubInter> getEffects() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and similarly any other interface which uses itself as the generic type will have its implementing class contain a method that returns a list of that interface.

However, I can't implement the super interface type correctly:

```
class SuperImpl implements SuperInter<SuperInter> {

    @Override
    public List<SuperInter> getEffects() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Besides raw types warning, I get:

```
Bound mismatch: The type SuperInter is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends SuperInter<T>> of the type SuperInter<T>
```

I guess because the class does not extends itself. How can I achieve this?

Comment: i might be wrong, but due to the recursion the only right way to write is is the following: `class SuperImpl implements SuperInter<SuperInter<SuperInter<SuperInter<SuperInter<[to infinity]>>>> {`

Answer (score 2):

You can declare it as follows:

```
class SuperImpl implements SuperInter<SuperImpl> {

    @Override
    public List<SuperImpl> getEffects() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can't have the interface returned like in the subclass/interface case, only the implementing class?

Comment: Try having it return `List<? super T>`

Comment: (In your deleted answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45367014/1441122) you can use the two-arg overload of `Comparator.comparing`.)

Comment: @StuartMarks i don't understand what this relates to. Also do you know the answer to my comment?

Comment: @Mark My comment is completely unrelated. I was attempting to contact Eran regarding a deleted answer, which doesn't allow commenting.

Comment: @Mark Re your question/comment, offhand no, but I'll post if I think of anything.